# Collecting the numbers from a string in python

Tags: python, regex, file

How can i collect the numbers 0.0, 0.64 and 0.08, 0.72 and put them into variables?
string looks like this

```
{"object" "rectangle" "param1" {"Type1" "Type2"} "param2" {{0.0 0.64} {0.08 0.72}} "smth" 0 "point1" 0 "point2" }
```

I'm trying to do this on Python

Comment: This *almost* looks almost a JSON file. Is your original input JSON?

Comment: Python has a builtin `json` module for JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get those numbers:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> mystr = """
... {"object" "rectangle" "param1" {"Type1" "Type2"} "param2" {{0.0 0.64} {0.08 0.72}} "smth" 0 "point1" 0 "point2" }
... """
>>> findall("-?\d+\.\d+", mystr)
['0.0', '0.64', '0.08', '0.72']
>>> var1, var2, var3, var4 = findall("-?\d+\.\d+", mystr)
>>> var1
'0.0'
>>> var4
'0.72'
>>>
```

Or, if you want them as floats, you can do this:

```
>>> var1, var2, var3, var4 = map(float, findall("-?\d+\.\d+", mystr))
>>> var1
0.0
>>> var4
0.72
>>>
```

Lastly, here is a breakdown of the Regex pattern:

```
-?   # An optional hyphen (for negative numbers)
\d+  # One or more digits
\.   # A period (the decimal point)
\d+  # One or more digits
```

Answer (score 1):

This look similar to a JSON type file, but not quite. Life may be easier if you can get it properly formatted use python's built-in `JSON` library. However, if it will always be the same type of format you can count of this regular expression to do a quick and dirty job:

```
data = """"{"object" "rectangle" "param1" {"Type1" "Type2"} "param2" {{0.0 0.64} {0.08 0.72}} "smth" 0 "point1" 0 "point2" }"""
r = re.compile('"param2" {{(\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+)} {(\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+)}}')
m = r.search(data)
[float(m.group(i)) for i in range(1,5)]
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.64, 0.08, 0.72]
```

Comment: so this should be able to capture Type1 and Type2 isnt it?
r = re.compile('"param1" {"\w+"\."\w+"}')

why this doesnt work?

Comment: @Streak yes, but that is the incorrect pattern. Try `r = re.compile('"param1" {"(\w+)" "(\w+)"}')`